# Changing the text format of a particular label in pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels, plot, axis

In this plot I want to change the color of a label in x-axis. For example I want to change the color of **Set1** to orange. It is possible to do it simply by `\textcolor{orange}{Set1}`, as you see in the code. But the moment I do the same for other labels like **Set2**, it does not compile anymore!

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [trim axis left,trim axis right]
    \tikzset{every pin/.style={pin distance=0.1em,font=\small}}
    \begin{axis}[
        width = \textwidth, height = 5cm,
        ybar,
        ymax=1000,
        ymode=log,
        log basis y={10},
        log ticks with fixed point,
        legend columns = -1, % Horizontal legend
        legend style={anchor=south east,draw=none,fill=none,at={(current axis.north east)},font=\scriptsize},
        symbolic x coords = {\textcolor{orange}{Set1}, Set2, Set3},
        xtick = {\textcolor{orange}{Set1}, Set2, Set3},
        xticklabel style = { rotate = 45, anchor = north east },
        enlarge x limits = 0.08,
        ylabel = {total runtime (ms)},
        bar width = 1mm,
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {(\textcolor{orange}{Set1}, 723.7) (Set2, 721.728)};
        \addplot coordinates {(\textcolor{orange}{Set1}, 199.424) (Set2, 195.702)};
        \addplot coordinates {(\textcolor{orange}{Set1}, 56.3) (Set2, 53.136) (Set3, 55.655)};
        \addplot coordinates {(\textcolor{orange}{Set1}, 34.5) (Set2, 34.559) (Set3, 33.915)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any idea about this weird problem?

[image]

Comment: I used ChatGPT and its solution is practical. It suggested using `\newcommand`  instead of changing the label, like `\newcommand{\coloredSetOne}{\textcolor{orange}{Set1}}` and defining label as `\coloredSetOne`. Any better solution?

Comment: A better solution by ChatGPT: The issue is that `symbolic x coords` is used to specify the x-axis labels, and it does not accept LaTeX commands like `\textcolor`. Therefore, when you try to use `\textcolor` in `symbolic x coords`, it breaks the code.

One solution to this problem is to use `xticklabels` instead of `symbolic x coords` to specify the x-axis labels. This way, you can use LaTeX commands like `\textcolor` to change the color of specific labels.

Comment: Do not use macros for the symbolic coords (that is for the strings that are used to identify the coords). This might work in certain cases, but often it does not. Instead use labels for the ticks which you can style as much as you want. (This is essentially the second solution you already found via ChatGPT it seems.)

Comment: Any better approach includes using your own ability to learn and to observe. Relying on AI won't help you, at least still for now: see the trouble it causes for even simple situations. Why ist that so? Because by result you can't distinguish AI from Artificial Incompetence, or by procedure from Acquired Incompetence. Or put in simple words: AI doesn't get enlightened, while you still might be ;-)